# YII2 - How to put conditional validation for dynamic form fild?

Tags: php, yii2

How to put conditional validation in to dynamic form this is the model file and address1 is the dynamic fileds

```html
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['client_id'], 'integer'],
        [['client_type', 'address1', 'address_type', 'address2', 'forn_address1', 'forn_address2', 'is_deleted', 'state', 'city', 'forn_city', 'forn_country', 'zip', 'forn_zip'], 'string'],
        [['added_on', 'updated_on'], 'safe'],
        [['zip','forn_zip'], 'match' ,'pattern'=> '/^[0-9]*$/' ,'message'=> 'Zip code must be numeric.'],
        [['address1', 'state', 'city', 'zip'], 'required', 
        'when' => function ($model) { 
            return $model->address_type == "domestic_address"; 
        }, 
        'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) { console.log($('div.address_type label input[type=radio]:checked').val());
        return $('div.address_type label input[type=radio]:checked').val() == 'domestic_address';}"],
        [['forn_address1', 'forn_city', 'forn_zip', 'forn_country'], 'required', 'when' => function ($model) { return $model->address_type == "foreign_address"; }, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) { console.log($('div.address_type label input[type=radio]:checked').val());
        return $('div.address_type label input[type=radio]:checked').val() == 'foreign_address';}"]
    ];
}
```

How to put conditional validation in to dynamic form ?

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Any example?

Comment: It would be nice to see what it was that you tried in order to have resolved this yourself, which would have shown us that you did research this before posting the question. When you try, you also learn. If someone just gives you an answer/solution, it would have all been for nothing and I say this for the/your future. You can then edit your post to contain something that may have failed; even that shows an effort on your part. Remember, we're always glad to help :-)

Comment: @Yupik He actually did something but for some reason deleted entire code from the question.

Comment: @GytisTenovimas well, noone will check edit history to answer the question :)

Comment: no, I am trying since past 3hours

Comment: Give an example of "conditional validation" (not in code, in words).

Comment: 1st let there are two dynamic fields 1 addresses and another is the city these two fields are again generated by click on add button because  these are yii2-dynamic forms and there is another field that is the radio button  like this   Domestic Address and Foreign Address  if I checked on Domestic Address then these two fields are required if I check Foreign Address then for  Foreign address field are required

Comment: also, I would not display javascript code in your rules. Write a script on the view side that includes the Javascript. Yii2 has a nice way to include assets. This way you will have a nice separation of layers (i.e. model, view, and controller). What you did is clever, but could be a little messy to maintain between developers.

Comment: Have you made any progress? Did the answer below help?

Comment: yes, I have solved that problem but below answer was not help me. thanks

Comment: Can you please share how did you resolved the situation?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Standalone Validator](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation#standalone-validators).

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */ 
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['address', 'validateAddress']
    ]
}

/**
* Check your address.
*/
public function validateAddress($attribute, $params, $validator)
{

   // 
   // You can access other model fields like so:
   // $this->address_type or $this->address or $this->other_field

   /* Add your conditions as you see fit.*/
   if (strtolower($this->address_type) = 'domestic_address')) {
       $this->addError($attribute, 'Address TYPE is too domestic');
   }
   // or for example 
   if (strtolower($this->address) = '123 Road-ABC')) {
       $this->addError($attribute, 'Address is goofy');
   }

}
```